How to Compute Returns from Cumulative PnL and Price Data for Portfolio Optimization in Algorithmic Trading?
I have a set of algorithmic strategies. Each strategy focus on a specific financial product and generates entry and exit Long or Short signals. So for each strategy we can have periods in which we are long, flat or short. The holding period can change. For each strategy, I have already computed the cumulative PnL given an initial capital. What is important to remark in my context is that each strategy can open one position at a time and the volume of the position for the financial product is always constant = Q, so we are not reinvesting all the profits that we gain from a successful position into the next position and we have an initial amount of money C.
Goal
Create a return dataset for each strategy (and each time-frame) to run a Portfolio optimization algorithm and compute the optimal amount of money invested in each strategy.
Questions
The question is how to compute the returns from cumulative PnL and price data such that I have a consistent return dataset.
Current approach
Given an hourly strategy with Buy or Sell signals and the associated cumulative PnL, we can define absolute returns as the change in cumulative PnL for each instant of time, each hour, as:
$ \Delta PnL_t = PnL_t - PnL_{t-1}. $
My idea was to compute the returns for each time instant t as:
$$ R_t = \frac{\Delta PnL_{t}}{(Price_{t-1} * Q)} $$
where $Price_{t-1}$ defines the price of the financial product at the time preceding the one at which we are calculating return and Q is the volume of the open position in which we are long( or short).
Creating a dataset based on those R_t works well when analyzing returns generated by the same position (when I talk about "same" position we mean being long/short given a signal and not closing the trade, such that for each instant of time there is a generated return computed from open equity).
Returns generated by the same position can be aggregated over time compounding them, using the sum of log-returns or the cumulative product of simple returns ($ R_{[t,T]}= \prod_{i=t}^{T} (1 + R_i) - 1.$)
The problem arises when I need to aggregate or to analyze together the percentage returns generated by different positions. This is due to the fact that money generated from a position is not entirely reinvested in the following trade, nor there is a fixed amount of money invested. So compounding over time the returns generated from different trades does not represent the perfect metric to evaluate the proficiency of the strategy.
Questions

The resampling of the dataset: if I want to resample the dataset from hourly granularity to daily granularity, how can I aggregate returns from different positions? Should I change the returns definition?
Related to previous questions, how should I compute the "Expected Return" for each strategy for portfolio optimization?
The backtesting: as mentioned above, since the money gained from one position are not completely reinvested in the following one, compounded returns differ from an hypothetical generated PnL. How can I reconcile the difference between compounded returns and actual PnL in backtesting?

